# In Drupal 7 Views what is the php code to validate a field against a contextual filter argument?

Tags: 7, views

Currently I am using the path url to pass in arguments:

path: /%/%/%

On the 3rd argument I am loading a Taxonomy term. I also have a field loaded called: **field: device type**

What do I have to put in my contextual filter validation PHP code? I did a dsm($view), but my device type shows recursion. I'm not sure how to reference the field properly to create a conditional to compare it to the contextual argument.

[image]

Comment: you're asking about how to get or use the third argument from the URL or all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a code sample of my contextual filter validation code for drupal 7 views 3 validation.

My view contains a page display with the following path set: **blog/%/%/%**

Here is a sample path argument of what I'm trying to accomplish: 
**Path URL:** blog/7/node-title/taxonomy-name

```
if ( is_numeric(arg(1)) && is_string(arg(3)) ) {   
//check to make sure arg 1 is text and arg 2 is a string

  $node = node_load(arg(1));
//load the node

  $terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name(arg(3));
//get the terms array and TID from arg 3.

  if (!empty($terms)) {
    $first_term = array_shift($terms);
    foreach($node->field_repair_states_region['und'] as $x => $y) {
      if( $y['tid'] == $first_term->tid ) { return TRUE; }
//make sure the TID matches the TID to the node.

    } 
  }
}
```

Screenshot of Validation Page: http://prntscr.com/1dcl4v

Screenshot of View: http://prntscr.com/1dclly